# How to limit the value of the textbox in vb 6.0

Tags: vb6, textbox, integer

I am doing a marks updating database system. I need to limit each of my textbox to be in the value of less than 100, when its over than 100 or when its not number, a message box will pop up and the data won't be save until the user change the mistake. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Hiren Pandya, but I thought I would add my own take as well.

Be aware that converting a string to a numerical value is not trivial, but the [Val](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7beh1x9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), [CInt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy.aspx), CDBl etc. functions in VB6 can all give you behavior that close to what you want. (some of those links are for VB.Net, but can still be valuable).  You want to make sure you are thinking about digit grouping, positive/negative, decimal separators, etc. when you are validating user input on your own.  Most of the time, the built-in functions are good enough.

```
Private Sub Text1_Change()
    On Error GoTo Err_Handler
    Dim text As String
    text = Text1.text
    If IsNumeric(text) = True Then

        'If you only want integers...
        Dim value As Integer
        value = Val(text)
            If value <= 100 And value > 0 Then
            'The value is good so whatever stuff you need to do
            'And then leave the procedure
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    'Let everything else fall through here...
Err_Handler:
    MsgBox "Invalid input."
    'Other stuff to prevent saving
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

In the properties of the text box, set MaxLength to 2.

If you want a message, in the text box Change event, you could do...

```
If Len(txtBox.Text)>2 then msgbox...
```

then add your message in the messagebox.

I could go into more detail if you need it. Some thing like below...

```
Private Sub Text1_Change()
If Len(Text1) > 6 Then
    Text1 = " "    
    MsgBox "Not more than six"    
    Text1.SetFocus    
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: may I ask what is the use of SetFocus, can you go into more detail? Thanks :)

Comment: SetFocus will set the focus (cursor) on the textbox.. Means after having the message box, when user comes back to the form, the cursor will be in the textbox on which the SetFocus has been applied..